# How to concatenate unwrapped optional and string

Tags: xcode, types, swift3

Executing the code below should open a new URL at `baseURL + path`. However, it results in the following error:

```
error:Argument label String do not match any available overloads in let url = URL(String:urlString)
```

The `baseURL` and `path` variables come from a JSON file. `baseURL` is a string and `path` is an unwrapped optional.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let newPath = path! as! String
    let urlString = baseURL + newPath
    let url = URL(String:urlString)
    let requestObj = URLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: "I'm getting error in let url = URL(String:urlString)". How we will know what error are you getting ?

Comment: I'm getting this error:Argument label String do not match any available overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `baseURL` and `path` are of type `String`

```
let baseURL = "http://10.150.160.170"
let path = "/welcome-page"
let urlString = baseURL + path
let url = URL(string: urlString)
let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
```

Comment: path is unwrapped optional, i'm converting it to string in newPath,however i'm getting error  in  `let url = URL(String:urlString)`, saying Argument label String do not match any available overloads

Comment: use lowerCase `string` in this line `let url = URL(String:urlString)`